# JSONata group, sort and return first item per group

Tags: jsonata

I have an advanced JSONata request.  This is my JSON

```
[
  {
    "id": "a1",
    "grouping": "A",
    "text": "Lorum ipsum",
    "created": "2023-01-01T13:42"
  },
  {
    "id": "a2",
    "grouping": "A",
    "text": "Epsom minor",
    "created": "2023-02-01T20:02"
  },
{
    "id": "a3",
    "grouping": "B",
    "text": "Ipsum Lorum",
    "created": "2023-01-01T13:42"
  }
]
```

I would like to group by "grouping", sort by "created" in descending order, and only the first entry per group.

I would like the return result to be

```
[
  {
    "id": "a2",
    "grouping": "A",
    "text": "Epsom minor",
    "created": "2023-02-01T20:02"
  },
{
    "id": "a3",
    "grouping": "B",
    "text": "Ipsum Lorum",
    "created": "2023-01-01T13:42"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression should do it:

```
$^(>created){ grouping: $ }
  ~> $each(function ($value) { $value[0] })
```

So, first, we sort the list by `created` using the [order-by operator](https://docs.jsonata.org/path-operators#---order-by) then, we group it by `grouping` with the help of the [reduce operator](https://docs.jsonata.org/path-operators#---reduce), and finally, we pick the first entry within each group using the [$each function](https://docs.jsonata.org/object-functions#each).

Check out your example live on the playground: https://stedi.link/Ad4ZDix